# Email sample for requesting a dataset for a joint paper

Tags: publications, phd

Im interested in collaborating with a researcher and he is willing to collaborate and share his data with me for the joint paper but I need to send him a formal email and ask if I can look at the data and use it for the paper? Does someone have a sample email?

Many thanks

Comment: Just write down what you want, why you want it, what you plan to do with it and what you offer in return. Wrap this in some standard polite letter boilerplate ("Dear Sir or Madam", "Thank you for your consideration. Please don't hesitate to contact me if you need further information. Best Regards") and you have your letter.

Comment: Roland: Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you say that he is willing to collaborate, that means that you already talked to him about it and the formal email is just a prerequisite for his institute/university. Thus, it is most likely different from others and unique to this case, so it would be best to just ask him directly about the format he needs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where can I find a sample of a formal email for a general request? it could be for any institute or university, I just need to take a look at a sample before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh. As mentioned above, they agreed already, thus the mail is a formality. Now, just be formal.

> Dear Prof. Tihiy,
>
> Would it be possible for me to access the raw data from your recent work "Sepulki and Sepulation"? I am planning research on the forms of sepulation in vaccum and your data would be of immense importance to me.
>
> Of course, should my research be fruitful, a `<meaningful outcome, such as a joint paper>` would arise.
>
> Best regards,
>
> John Doe

Comment: When you write an e-mail to a professor, do you not capitalize the first word of the first sentence? Bad example.

Comment: Notice the comma instead of full stop after the name.

Comment: [Why, after the salutation and name of addressee, followed by a comma, is the following word capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/208606/31134)

Comment: Oh, oka-aaay. It's different then in English than in my native language.